# Subtract one Django MySQL from another

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have two models as follows:

```
class UserSelection(models.Model):
    soccerseason = models.IntegerField()
    fixturematchday = models.IntegerField()
    userid = models.IntegerField()
    campaignno = models.IntegerField()
    teamselection = models.IntegerField()
    teamselectionid = models.IntegerField()
    teamresult = models.CharField(max_length = 1)
    teamgoals = models.IntegerField()

class StraightredTeam(models.Model):
    teamid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    teamname = models.CharField(max_length=36)
    teamcode = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    teamshortname = models.CharField(max_length=24)
    currentteam = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

    def natural_key(self):
        return self.teamshortname

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'straightred_team'
```

In my view I create variables that contain the results of two queries as follows:

```
currentTeams = StraightredTeam.objects.filter(currentteam=1).order_by('teamshortname')

cantSelectTeams = UserSelection.objects.filter(campaignno=398169).order_by('fixturematchday')
```

Basically, I would like to exclude teams from the currentTeams selection that are in the cantSelectTeams.  The fields that link the two are teamid from StraighRedTeam and teamselectionid from UserSelection.

I know I can run these two queries separately and create a list by manipulating it in python but I just wondered if I could do it using just queries, maybe by combining the two?

If you need any more information just ask.  If you do not like the question and down vote it then please give feedback why so I can ask better questions in the future.

Many thanks in advance, Alan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you're doing it wrong. Really really wrong. You should better use ForeignKeys to link models together.

Answering the question, yes you can do it, and it's pretty simple:

```
cantSelectTeams = UserSelection.objects.filter(campaignno=398169).order_by('fixturematchday')

currentTeams = StraightredTeam.objects.filter(currentteam=1).exclude(teamid__in=cantSelectTeams.values_list('teamselectionid', flat=True)).order_by('teamshortname')
```

Comment: Oooops, I had done that on previous tables.  I am just fiddling and not done it here.  Good shout.

Comment: Pynchia,  many thanks for your support on this question.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: please have a look at the [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) to see why/how the solution works